# How to increase speed,performance of Google Web Application.?

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, hibernate-annotations

I am using spring mvc (annotations), hibernate,Cloud sql in (Google) web application project.
There is 30 seconds limitation for each request to finish. If internet speed is little slow, then we are getting "HardDeadLine Exception" for every page. 
what should i do for it.?

when application load first time below log is printing, after that i never get below line in logs, But when HardDeadLine Exception is coming then below line found in logs.

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

what is the reason for it ? why it initialize after once it has initialized.?

Comment: Do you know what requests are causing your exception?  Every time App Engine starts a new instance, the dependent Java libraries are loaded, which, in the case of Spring, can be large.  The larger the libraries, the longer it will take.  Once loaded, subsequent requests will be quicker – until another instance starts up, when you may exceed the deadline again.

Comment: Try using warmup requests: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Warmup_requests

Comment: for each request it is throwing exception like bean creation exception, unable to get members of exception. etc. One page comes after some time but again click on that page throws exception. what should i need to do for that .? This issues is coming 2 day before. is this because of large database.? why spring initialize framework for each request.?

Comment: converting spring annotation into spring xml, will increase it increase performance..?